# Monkey patch ruby instance method, using the original definition?

Tags: ruby, dynamic-programming, monkeypatching

I want to open a class, and redefine an instance method, using the original implementation.

```
# Original class
class Test
  def my_method
    # do something
  end
end

# Monkey patched version
class Test
  def my_method
    wrap_my_method do
       # call a copy of original my_method?
    end
  end
end
```

With class methods I would copy the method into a proc, and then call it.
How can I do something similar with instance methods?

Comment: Try `super` - https://medium.com/rubycademy/the-super-keyword-a75b67f46f05

Comment: In this case I would want to monkey-patch framework code, which means I cannot subclass. The framework will call Test#my_method.

Comment: Good point! My bad

Comment: @mrzasa Looks promising, thanks!